# API request to same domain

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

Good day!

I have a PHP based web application, that I am looking to add a Wordpress to.

The main application is in the root folder, and wordpress is installed in /wp

In order to get WP content into my application, I am using a JSON API (http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/)

Then, from the application, I am calling the API with CURL.

Is this a good way to go about calling the API? CURL seems to be very slow, and I think it has something to do with sessions, and the fact that it is requesting a url on the same domain.

Or perhaps someone could offer a suggestion on a better way to go about getting wordpress content into a non-wordpress based application.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It won't be because of "session" or "same domain", its most likely slow because the plugin is sitting on top of the wordpress stack and wordpress is loading quite a lot of content before the plugin initializes and responds to requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The only thing that causes me to be suspicious of something further is that if I make the call from a browser, its almost instant, but from CURL, its very slow ... sometimes 5-10 seconds. What would you suggest doing to troubleshoot?

Comment: As a long shot, can you try adding this option to your curl handle... `curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Expect:'));` and see if that speeds up your local requests? I have seen curl run slow with requests greater than 1024 bytes

Comment: I tried adding curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Expect:')); but that made no difference.

However, adding curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1); speeds up the request a lot. what does that indicate?

Comment: Do you call many curl requests per script execution? If so one is failing to connect, otherwise if its only just one and you still get a valid response, then not much.

Comment: Just one request. Hmm, strange. Thanks for the help